# optimizing code performance

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization

Hi i am kind of new in c++. I was trying to optimize my code. My code includes two for loops with a if block inside the second loop. first loop will iterate for 10^14 times and inner for loop will iterate for 10^4 times. My code is as folows

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
#include<math.h>
#include<thread>

using namespace std;

signed long long run,i,j;

int main()
{
    run=0;
    for (i=0;i<100000000000000;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<10000;j++)
        {
            run=run+1;
        }
    }

    cout<<run<<"\n";        
}
```

time it is takling to complete is around 1 day. So I was using thread in my code to make it first. But it is showing to include -std=c++0x. So where to include this?
Is there anyone who would like to help me out?

Comment: Ummm... I honestly think you should start with some tutorials on c++ and `threads`. There is so much what is wrong IMO and your understanding seem to be so low that Comments+Answer would end up being a tutorial anyways.

Comment: Why did you write `using namespace std` twice, in the middle of includes? And a third time after that.

Comment: @Mr.Pandey Most of your edits seem to be indentation-related, and either doesn't improve the indentation much, or makes it worse. Can you please stop doing that?

Comment: Please, when using C headers in C++ use the appropriate header e.g. `ctime` instead of `time.h`

Comment: I'm going to optimize your code right now: `(10^18) - 1`

Comment: `conio.h` and `dos.h`? Instead of writing non-standard code using an IDE which is decades old and has been discontinued for years, switch to something more modern. There are tons of good free C++ IDEs out there.

Comment: @perencia Precisely my thought :-) But it's `10^18`, no `-1`...

Comment: The maximum long-long is around 4e18, and you're just counting up to 1e18. You're trying to write something that takes a long time, and it does! I suppose it might help to unroll the inner loop like this: `for(j=1000; --j>=0;){run++;run++;run++;run++;run++;run++;run++;run++;run++;run++;}`

Comment: probably belongs to codereview.so

Comment: I don't know what you're doing with fstream, stdio.h, dos.h, time.h, stdlib.h, conio.h in the simple code using cout here. And I don't think DOS compilers support `long long` since they're even older than the first C standard, and long long is not available till C99 or some extensions. Even if it does support, you shouldn't use DOS anymore. Their compilers are immature, optimizations are very bad and it's painfully slow to do 64-bit arithmetics in 16-bit mode

Comment: and if your can count at 1GHz or 1 billion times a second, it takes more than 31 years to count to 10^18. Even you can do it at 4GHz in a 8 core CPU, it still takes at least almost 1 year no matter how you optimize it

Comment: note that DOS compilers are pre-standard C so it cannot support C++0x. You cannot run this program in 1 day too

Comment: @Dukeling:I just did those edits to improve the readability of the code.

Comment: @Mr.Pandey It may have slightly improved readability here, but they key word here is "slightly". After your edit, still none of the code in blocks lined up (look how the code looks after the last edit). You should always try to fix it as much as possible. And then I saw a case where your edit [was actively harmful](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23414682/revisions) - having everything on the same indentation makes it a lot more difficult to spot where blocks start and end.

Comment: @Dukeling:Ok! Got it.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Not sure what you're going on about but it's fairly obvious that the OP isn't using a DOS compiler.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes of course I know it. Just talking a bit about the conio.h and dos.h in the include part

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Both of those ship with Visual Studio. I'm not saying they should be used (because they shouldn't), but your three consecutive comments about performance of native DOS compilers is not relevant. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd optimise it as follows, but good compilers might do that anyway:

```
#include<iostream>

signed long long run,i,j;

int main()
{
    i = 100000000000000;
    j = 10000;
    run = i * j;

    std::cout << run << '\n';        
}
```

Comment: A better optimization (which a good compiler would probably do) is: `int main(){cout << 1000000000000000000 << "\n";}`. There's no need for all the unused includes and repeated `using` declarations either.

Comment: You can also optimize out some of those headers.

Comment: Thanks. I would have also done the same thing what you have done. I have simplified my whole code and posted here. Yes, some header files are old also. For that I am going through some tutorials.  I want to thread my inner for loop to make my original code faster. How to do that? Would you please like to help me ? I am using i7 computer. For one order increase of inner loop iteration numbers, whole program is going to take 7 hours more to execute.

Answer (score 0):

`-std=c++0x` is a compiling option, and it tells the compiler you are using C++11 standard.

You might want to take a look at a link like this one http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node3.html regarding compiling.